# Descriptive statistics and boxplot for repeated measurements?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, median

---

**update: problems were caused by typo's**

- Question 1: `summarize` did not organise output by each group due to a typo in the third line (`median_dbp=(diastolic_bp)` should have been `median_dbp=median(diastolic_bp)`).
- Question 2: the boxplot did not group by `drug` because the call to `fill=drug` was outside of the `aes` mapping but it should have been inside (correct code: `ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timepoint, y=diastolic_bp, fill=drug))`.

---

for an assignment I have the following data of a small crossover study where two drugs, A and B, are compared for their effect on the diastolic blood pressure (DBP). Each patient in the study receives the two treatments in a random order and separated in time (“wash-out” period) so that one treatment does not influence the blood pressure measurement obtained after administering the other treatment (i.e. to rule out carry-over effect). The data looks as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

mydata <- structure(list(pt_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 
16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Timepoint 1", "Timepoint 2"), class = "factor"), 
    drug = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Drug A", 
    "Drug B"), class = "factor"), diastolic_bp = c(100, 112, 
    116, 114, 108, 110, 104, 114, 114, 98, 116, 102, 100, 96, 
    103, 92, 89, 103, 96, 116, 78, 127, 131, 129, 124, 106, 128, 
    133, 118, 108, 91, 109, 113, 98, 118, 112)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

My first question is regarding obtaining a mean and standard deviation (as well as a mean + percentiles) for each treatment group per timepint. My code:

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(timepoint, drug) %>% 
  summarise(mean_dbp=mean(diastolic_bp, na.rm=TRUE), 
            sd_dbp=sd(diastolic_bp, na.rm=TRUE), 
            median_dbp=(diastolic_bp), 
            p25_dbp=quantile(diastolic_bp, probs=0.25), 
            p75_dbp=quantile(diastolic_bp, probs=0.75))

# This returns a line per patient:
# A tibble: 36 x 7
# Groups:   timepoint, drug [4]
   timepoint   drug   mean_dbp sd_dbp median_dbp p25_dbp p75_dbp
   <fct>       <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1         100     96     108 
 2 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1         108     96     108 
 3 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1          98     96     108 
 4 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1          96     96     108 
 5 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1          92     96     108 
 6 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1         127     96     108 
 7 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1         129     96     108 
 8 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1         106     96     108 
 9 Timepoint 1 Drug A     105.  14.1          91     96     108 
10 Timepoint 1 Drug B     114.   9.64        116    110.    116.
# ... with 26 more rows
```

But this produces calculations for each row in the dataset. What I was expecting was number one number for each combination of `drug` and `timepoint`...

Then I tried to make a boxplot per timepoint and group as follows:

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timepoint, y=diastolic_bp), fill=drug) + geom_boxplot()
```

But this does not include the grouping variable `drug`:
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Check your parentheses. You haven't included `fill=drug` in aes().

Comment: Stefan has the answer to your problem!

Comment: Thanks! Including it in the `aes` solved the issue regarding the boxplot. Would you also know how to solve the issues regarding `summarise`? For example, I'm trying to get a mean and SD for `diastolic_bp` at each `timepoint` for each `drug`, but my code does not give me that.

Comment: Please do not use existing questions to ask other questions (each post should ask only one specific question that can be answered, and not  move the goalpost after a correct answer was given....)

Comment: Ah I should have been more specific. When I say `Firstly I am trying to produce mean and standard deviations as well as medians and 25th and 75th percentiles for each treatment group at each timepoint (so per group and timepoint 1 mean and 1 median etc.). My code:` That was meant as a fist question... Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question so it is more clear.

Comment: Maybe: mydata %>% group_by(drug, timepoint) %>% 
  summarise("q25" = quantile(diastolic_bp, c(0.25)),
            "q50" = quantile(diastolic_bp, c(0.50)),
            "q75" = quantile(diastolic_bp, c(0.75)),
            mean = mean(diastolic_bp),
            sd = sd(diastolic_bp))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want. `drug` needs to go in aes.

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=timepoint, y=diastolic_bp, fill=drug)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted.
Also I was trying to produce the medians and 25th and 75th percentiles with the `summarise` argument of my code, but it produces a median and percentiles for each row of the data and not grouped. Would you also know what I am doing wrong there?

Thanks!

Comment: Try mydata %>% 
  group_by(drug) %>%  
  summarise(quantile = scales::percent(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)),
            diastolic_bp_quantiles = quantile(diastolic_bp, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))

Comment: There was a typo in my code at the `summarise` part: ` median_dbp=(diastolic_bp),` should be `median_dbp=median(diastolic_bp),`. Thanks again for your help!